# How to fix php getting select option value instead of text?

Tags: php, html

I have issues posting my select option values from html form to php back-end

Here are my codes:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
<select name="approver" class="form-control" autofocus>

        <option selected disabled value="0">— Select Approver —</option>
        <option selected disabled value="1">User A</option>
        <option selected disabled value="2">User B</option>

      </select>
</form>
```

submit.php:

```
$approver = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['approver']);
```

Is there a way for php to receive the value of the option, eg. 1, instead of the text inside the option tag?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `value` of the option is what's always being sent. So you should be getting `0`, `1` or `2` from your result. If not, do you have some jQuery or JavaScript here? And how come they're all disabled *and* selected?

Comment: Remove the `disabled` attribute from options and try

Answer (score 0):

"selected disabled" attributes should be used for the first option(generally which is not really an option for the user to select). It is used so that the user cannot choose the first option again after changing the option. Remove the "selected disabled" attributes from other options.

```
<select name="approver" class="form-control" autofocus>
    <option selected disabled value="0">— Select Approver —</option>
    <option value="1">User A</option>
    <option value="2">User B</option>
</select>
```